# Redis namespacing basics

Tags: ruby, namespaces, redis

I am really new to Redis and have been using it along with my Ruby on Rails (Rails 2.3 and Ruby 1.8.7) application using the redis gem for simple tagging functionality as a key value store. I recently realized that I could use it to maintain a user activity feed as well.

The thing is I need the tagging data (stored as key =>  Sets) in memory and its extremely important to determine results for tagging related operations, where as for the activity feed the data could be deleted on a first in first out basis. Assuming I store X number of activities for every user

Is it possible that I could namespace the redis data sets and have one remain permanently in memory and have the other stay temporarily in the memory. What is the general approach when one uses unrelated data sets that need to have different durations of survival in memory.

Would really appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need to define a specific namespace for this. With Redis, you can use the [EXPIRE](http://redis.io/commands/expire) command to set a timeout on a key by key basis.

The general policy regarding key expiration is defined in the configuration file:

```
# MAXMEMORY POLICY: how Redis will select what to remove when maxmemory
# is reached? You can select among five behavior:
#
# volatile-lru -> remove the key with an expire set using an LRU algorithm
# allkeys-lru -> remove any key accordingly to the LRU algorithm
# volatile-random -> remove a random key with an expire set
# allkeys->random -> remove a random key, any key
# volatile-ttl -> remove the key with the nearest expire time (minor TTL)
# noeviction -> don't expire at all, just return an error on write operations
#
```

For your purpose, the volatile-lru policy should be set.

You just have to call EXPIRE on the keys you want to be volatile, and let Redis evict them. However please note it is difficult to guarantee that the oldest keys will be evicted first once the timeout has been triggered. More explanations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010789/configuring-redis-to-consistently-evict-older-data-first/9069196#9069196).

For your specific use case however, I would not use key expiration but rather try to simulate capped collections. If the activity feed for a given user is represented as a list of objects, it is easy to LPUSH the activity objects, and use [LTRIM](http://redis.io/commands/ltrim) to limit the size of the list. You get FIFO behavior and keep memory consumption under control for free.

UPDATE:

Now, if you really need to isolate data, you have two main possibilities with Redis:

- using two distinct databases. Redis database are identified by an integer, and you can have several of them per instance. Use the [select command](http://redis.io/commands/select) to switch between databases. Databases can be used to isolate data, but not to assign them different properties (like an expiration policy for instance).
- using two distinct instances. An empty Redis instance is a very light process. So several of them can be started without any problem. It is actually the best and the more scalable way to isolate data with Redis. Each instance can have its own policies (including eviction policy). The clients should open as many connections as instances.

But again, you do not need to isolate data to implement your eviction policy requirements.

Comment: Thanks Didier but is there a way I can separate the keys that are used for tagging from the ones that are used for activity feed. Is there any way i can prevent those keys from expiring by any expiration policy. How does one use Redis when working with two separate data sets which are not related in any way.

Comment: That was my point: you do not have to separate them. Just use the EXPIRE command on the ones which should expire. Now if you really want to isolate data, you have two options: different databases or different instances. I update my answer.